# save recursion output to text file

Tags: c++, winapi, recursion

I am trying to recursively list the files in a directory. However when I save the output to a text file, it works, but the file contents keep being reset.  So the file size will be 2Kb, and then it is reset to 1Kb, 30Kb reset to 1Kb, and so on. The code is not saving all the output to the text file and only some of the last lines are saved to output.txt.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void listDir(wchar_t * szCurrentDirectory);

int main()
{
    // return current directory where app run
    DWORD nBufferLength = MAX_PATH;
    wchar_t szCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(nBufferLength, szCurrentDirectory);

    listDir(szCurrentDirectory);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void listDir(wchar_t * szCurrentDirectory)
{
    wchar_t addPath[MAX_PATH] = L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];
    swprintf(buf, MAX_PATH,L"%s%s", szCurrentDirectory, addPath);

    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(buf, &FindFileData);
    wofstream myfile("c:/output.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            do
            {
                // Check if is a folder or not.
                if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)
                {
                    // Ignore current folder and parent folder.
                    if (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L".") && wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") != 0)
                    {
                        if (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"$RECYCLE.BIN") != 0)
                        {
                            // return current directory where app run
                            wchar_t filepath[10000];
                            // Append slash to current directory.
                            swprintf(filepath, 10000, L"%s%s%s", szCurrentDirectory, L"\\", FindFileData.cFileName);
                            // Output the file.
                            myfile << filepath << endl;

                            if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                            {
                                // Recursive 
                                listDir(filepath);
                            } // if directory
                        } // if not recycle bin
                    } // if not . or ..
                } if not reparse point
            } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);

            FindClose(hFind);
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

try to run the app in c: drive and look the output in output.txt. the output keep reset.

Comment: ***the output keep reset*** Its best not to open the output file multiple times recursively. Pass the open file as a parameter instead.

Comment: @drescherjm how to pass to parameter. i don't have idea cause its only fewline what i need to pass?

Comment: It's the same way you passed `szCurrentDirectory`. Change `void listDir(wchar_t * szCurrentDirectory)` to `void listDir(wofstream & myfile,wchar_t * szCurrentDirectory)` then have the caller open the file the same way you opened it in listDir. Note: you must remove the opening code from listDir when you do this.

Comment: @drescherjm i dont have idea really. u say to pass function wofstream to parameter? can u straight answer. i dont know what u explain.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but if you changed to `if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) ||  (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L".") == 0)  ||(wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") == 0) ||
(wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"$RECYCLE.BIN") == 0)) { continue; }` you would save a *load* of indentation, and the code would be much easier to read.  Also if you tested the failure conditions and did an early return at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the open file as a parameter instead.

Change

```
void listDir(wchar_t * szCurrentDirectory)
```

to

```
void listDir(wofstream & myfile,wchar_t * szCurrentDirectory)
```

then remove the file opening code from `listDir()`.

Delete this line:

```
wofstream myfile("c:/output.txt");
```

And then call it in `main()` like this:

```
wofstream myfile("c:/output.txt");
listDir(myfile,szCurrentDirectory);
```

And finally in `listDir()` change

```
listDir(filepath);
```

to

```
listDir(myfile,filepath);
```

Comment: Just on general principles, I would make the parameter to `listDir` be `wostream& stream` - but then you have to change more lines.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is *definitely* to open the file once (in the main program), and then pass the stream into into the `listdir` function.

*However* ... there is an alternative.  It is not appropriate in this case, it might be in similar cases.  You can open the file in append mode, so the contents is *never* overwritten.  You just need to change the line where you open the file to:

```
std::wofstream myfile("c:/output.txt", std::ios_base::app);
```

The output will be written to the end of the file, preserving the existing contents.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in main and pass the handle as a second parameter to the listDir function.

Don't open it in listDir

Comment: what u means handle?  `wofstream myfile("c:/output.txt");, if (myfile.is_open()) or something` ?

Comment: Myfile is the handle. Sry on iPad so can't add code sample easily

Comment: so what the data type for myfile ?  parameter need data type to pass.

Comment: is it HANDLE myfile;?